# Python 3.4, django 1.7 oscar configuration

Tags: environment-variables, python-3.4, django-1.7, django-oscar

I have installed oscar in django 1.7 on windows 8 and followed the official tutorials but after the installation when i use `python django-admin.py startproject demoshop` command it gives an error :

```
(oscar) c:\Python34\Scripts>python django-admin.py startproject demoshop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I have also set the environment variables

[image: Environment Variables]

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Comment: What steps did you do to install Django?

Comment: followed the official documentation. 1. Installed python 2. installed pip 3. installed django 4. installed the virtualenv 5. Then installed oscar. All done on cmd as sugessted. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Well yes, but how did you install Django? `pip install Django`? What was the output? As the Python installation you're using currently can't access the installed Django.

Comment: It was the usual output after some ### loading on the cmd interface and yes I did pip install django

Comment: Its installed in the scripts folder not the root... Should it be on the root ?

Comment: It should be in a directory that you see when you do `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: This is the result of sys.path: >>> print(sys.path) ['', 'c:\\Python34\\python34.zip', 'c:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'c:\\Python34\\lib', 'c :\\Python34', 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python34\\site-pack ages', 'c:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages'] What should I do copy the oscar folder to the site-packages folder ?